# How to create redirect link in html or php with hidden constant credential?

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect, dom-events

Please help me to make redirect link or link which will perform the following activities.
The given code is:

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div class="loginDiv">
        <div id="divack"></div>
        </br>
        <form id="login" onsubmit="return submitForm();" name ="login" >
            <table>
               <tr>
               <td>Username </td><td><input type="hidden" id="txtUsername" name = "username" value="guest" />
               </tr>
               <tr>
               <td>Password </td><td><input type="hidden" id="txtPassword" name= "password"   value="guest1234"/>
               </tr>
               <tr><td><input type = "submit" id="btnSubmit" name="Login" value ="Login"/></td></tr>
             </table>
        </form>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

In the code on button click event it will redirect to some other page after checking credential from the database.

But I want to open direct on login page with particular fix credential which display some data in a grid.

So let consider the given code of login.html

when page is loaded on button click event it will redirect to some other page like home.html after checking credential from the database. According to the user access it will display some information.

Suppose, guest is one user and his password is guest1234

So instead on two manual redirection, I want all on one link.

So please help me to solve this problem.